# How to get the tag name of html using Python Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, tags

```
header = head.find_all('span')

[<span itemprop="name">Raj</span>, <span itemprop="street">24 Omni  Street</span>, <span itemprop="address">Ohio</span>, <span itemprop="Region">US</span>, <span itemprop="postal">40232</span>, <span class="number">334646344</span>]

print (header[0].tag)
print(header[0].text)

####output
None
Raj
...

####Expected output
Name
Raj
...
```

I could not able to extract all the value of span itemprop. It throws me None output. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`class 'bs4.element.Tag'`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) does not have a `tag` attribute, as itself *is* a `Tag`. From the docs:

> You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary.

So you've got the list of all the `span` tags, now just iterate the list and get their attribute that you want (i.e. `'itemprop'`):

```
spans = head.find_all('span')

for span in spans:
    try:
        print(span['itemprop'].decode().title() + ': ' + span.text)
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

output:

```
Name: Raj
Street: 24 Omni  Street
Address: Ohio
Region: US
Postal: 40232
```

Format the output or store the data as needed